# Polymorphism not always working when using reference

Tags: c++, oop, reference, polymorphism

I am having some unexpected behavior when using references on virtual methods.
Basically if I take a reference to an object of the base class, then change that reference to an object of the derived class.  When I call the virtual method, the base class method is called.

But if I take a reference to the base class and initialize it to the derived class, the derived method is called. Here is some code.

```
// A base class with a virtual that prints the class
class BaseClass {
    public:
            virtual void printMe();
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
            void printMe() override;
};

void BaseClass::printMe() {
    cout << "in Base"<<endl;
}

void DerivedClass::printMe() {
    cout << "in Derived"<<endl;
}


int main () {
    BaseClass bc = BaseClass();
    DerivedClass dc = DerivedClass();

    BaseClass * pbc = & bc ;
    pbc->printMe();            // Prints in Base
    pbc = & dc;
    pbc->printMe();            // Prints in Derived

    // Now with a reference
    BaseClass & bcr = bc;
    bcr.printMe();              // Prints in Base
    bcr = dc;
    bcr.printMe();              // Prints in Base   !!! 

    BaseClass & foo = dc;
    foo.printMe();              // Prints in Derived !!!
    return 0;
}
```

if someone could explain why the fourth print is not "in Derived" and why the fifth one is "in Derived" I would be grateful.

I (now) understand what has been posted about slicing - but under that logic I don't understand why

```
BaseClass & foo = dc;
foo.printMe()
```

calls the derived method

Nevermind   I see it now.

Comment: `bcr = dc;` does slicing.

Answer (score 1):

References must be initialized, but can *never* be assigned.

That means when you do: `bcr = dc;`, you're *not* making `bcr` refer to `dc`. Rather, you're taking the value of `dc`, "slicing" it to create a temporary object of the base class, and then assigning that temporary to the object to which `bcr` refers (which is `bc`). Afterwards, `dcr` still refers to `bc`, and `bc` has been assigned a new value (from the base class sub-object of `dc`).

Once a reference refers to one object (which must happen *as* the reference is create) it can/will always refer to that object. Any attempt at assignment will assign to that object to which it refers, *not* to the reference itself.

Comment: @gsamaras: Actually, I was 8 seconds ahead of you (but yeah, pretty much the same time).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
bcr = dc;
```

will not assign `dc` to `bcr`.

It will perform *Slicing*. It will chop off all the extra things the derived class has in comparison to the base class (it will treat the derived class like a base class in other words).